# How to plot a contour map in python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, visualization, pandas

I am trying to plot a contour map with the following data I have in 3 columns

1. one for the date and time (T)
2. one for the temperature - T1
3. last one with the temperature - T2

I am intending to make a contour map which shows the temperature T2 at (T,T1).
From what I have read and understood, I have to create a meshgrid with T and T1 and create a contour map with the meshgrid created and T2.
But most of the tutorials I have seen show it when T2 is a result of a function.
The temperatures T1 and T2 are observed at time T and they are not a result of any function.

EDIT
For example,

```
x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
xx, yy = meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True)
z = np.sin(xx**2 + yy**2) / (xx**2 + yy**2)
h = plt.contourf(x,y,z)
```

But in this case, z is another column of values and not a result of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to specify meshgrid as **np.meshgrid**, since it is part of the numpy library. You might find the following link helpful for more information ([numpy.meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)). Using the below code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True)
z = np.sin(xx**2 + yy**2) / (xx**2 + yy**2)
h = plt.contourf(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

If you simply use plt.contourf, the plot will be loaded but then the plt.show() command must be used to actually display the graph:
[image: Contour Map]